# How to model dimpled beer mug?

Tags: modeling

I have a hard time with beer mug modeling with complicated shape.

It has a dimpled shape and a smoothed area for printing logo opposite the ear.
I have a problem especially with making this flattish field for imprint. I tried to do it with snaping and shrinkwrap, boolean but it was not looking good.

How you would approach the subject? What tools would you use? Have anyone come across any tutorials that could help me?

I dare not ask, but could someone show me how to draw this? I have several mugs of a similar shape and need to learn how to make them. Thank you in advance

Best regards

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe use booleans? It will take a bit to align them all but I can't think of any procedural way.

Comment: Also it seems you have multiple questions in one. Are you wanting help *modeling* a mug or *texturing* it?

Comment: Hi :). It might help to check out the wireframe of paid models - [Example 01](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-mug-foam-model/1017599), [Example 02](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/beer-mugs-max/1029568)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Boolean with all this dimples will make vaery bad topology, which will be hard to clean up. Am I wrong? I will be rendering it with glass cycles, and I am affraid that this topology will have deffects in renders. 
I need help with modeling, the glass texturing is not a problem.

Comment: The Example 01 looks great. 
I would love to buy this model, but I'm afraid that all modifiers will be applied and I won't be able to learn much from the finished file. What do you think?

Comment: What techniques do you think were used to model Example 01?

Answer (score 3):

[image: example render]

I would create a **simple version** of the jar first to get a better impression of the 3D model. Especially the sizes and proportions of the dimples and the crease at the top edge can be gotten wrong easily. The *simple version* can be used as a target for the ***Shrinkwrap* modifier** to shape a *detailed version* of the jar.

For the dimples, a clean low-poly topology is recommended. A **detailed version** of the jar can be created quickly with the ***Array* and *Simple Deform* modifiers** once you have modeled a single seamless stripe with the dimples.

### Prerequisite

Start modeling at the world origin (0, 0, 0) in front view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) so that the *Simple Deform* modifier works properly. A plane should be rotated by 90° along the X-axis in *Edit* mode.

Now and then you need to apply modifiers. Make a backup copy of your model (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) before you apply the modifier.

### The Simple Version of the Jar

[image: simple jar]

1. Import your image as a reference. (There is an add-on that comes with Blender. You just need to enable it in the *User Preferences*. Then you can import the image with *Add > Image > As Reference*)
2. Trace the outer shape of the jar with a single vertice that you extrude a few times. Use the default cube or a new object, switch to *Edit* mode, and merge all vertices to a single vert (<kbd>M</kbd>). Then extrude the vertice to create an "outline".
3. Duplicate the outline, and scale it down a bit to create the inner part. Then connect both parts (select two verts and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect them)
4. Use the *Screw* modifier to create the jar.

### The Detailed Version And the Dimples

To create the detailed version, model a single "stripe", then duplicate and bend it with the *Array* and *Simple Deform* modifiers.

If you are poorly versed in topology (like me) use a reference. The shape of a dimple is fairly simple. It's a square that turns into a circle shape. This can be done with a simple subdivided plane and the *Loop Tools* add-on that comes with Blender. Just enable it in the *User Preferences*.

After you have the inner circle, extrude and scale <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> the outer loop, merge the vertices <kbd>M</kbd>, and add cuts <kbd>K</kbd> with the knife tool where you need them to create the edge flow. You want to have one single pattern element that you can repeat.

[image: pattern element]

The dimples are offset by half a width, creating two bands around the pitcher. So once you have modeled one single dimple, you can duplicate it, and use *Array* modifiers to create a larger area of it. Then you have something like this (left side):

[image: creating the stripe]

Now you can merge the parts and remove everything that repeats to create a "stripe"/"slice". Then fix the top and the bottom parts. You only need half of a dimple and can apply a *Mirror* modifier to get the repeating stripe (right side of the screenshot).

[image: modifiers]

Now you have this, you can use a bunch of modifiers to create the jar. Add an *Array* modifier and a *Simple Deform* modifier to create the jar. A *Weld* modifier to merge the beginning and the end of the bent plane. Last but not least, use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to project the pattern plane on the *simple version* of the jar. You need to move the plane a bit along the Y-axis so it surrounds the simple version.

[image: dimples]

Make a backup, apply the modifiers, extrude the upper part, and create the bottom. You can create a vertex group if you just want to shrinkwrap a part of the jar. The top here, for example.

To press in the dimples, select the central vertex in each circle, and scale them inward using *Proportional Editing*. Do this for each "band" individually so it scales inwards on the same Z-axis/height.

Comment: +1, a  really nice method. I'm thinking, you do actually have the topology there to make the part @JarekSz was drawing attention to.. (the flat panel) relatively simple?

Comment: Hello Blunder. Thank you for an interesting method and your time. Unfortunately, it's not entirely clear to me. I don't know how to make a field for printing, which is in the shape of a simplified mug (smooth, slightly convex and bent). I also don't know how to connect the array of upper circles to the array of lower pattern.

Comment: I am trying to do it on a flat mesh which I would like do bend next (with a Curve modifier and lattice). In this method it will be easy to "cut" field for printing in the center after applying arrays of circles and bottom panels). But on this stage I'm struggling to model the circles closer together. I didn't know how to paste image in this comment, so I paste it in my main question. See the image with circles spacing. First mesh is a mesh which I manually moved the circles to make it closer. Second is made with selecting every other vertex and beveling it. It makes the circles too far.

Comment: Hi there! Updating the question is the right way to add more info. Oh, I see now that you mentioned it. Indeed the *Shrinkwrap* modifier compresses the pattern. It can even create overlapping faces. I think I never noticed that in my try because I used the Mesh Filter brush (Smooth Surface) of the *Sculpt* mode. This operation drags the faces apart and the distance is equal. -- Wait, you actually want to have the circles of the pattern closer together? To me, the resulting dimples look fine if the circles are not that close together, don't they?

Comment: I've tried to create the area for the printing. The corners are a bit challenging because they always get rounder than they are on the reference image. The area can be created by removing a rectangular area of vertices. Then "grid fill" it. The *Simple Deform* modifier will bend it like the circle pattern. Finally, move the area along the normals so that the surface stands out a little. You can use a GN modifier to do it non-destructive. I'll update my answer and add a few images. This should also work with your approach (Curve modifier).